# radius of convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} n^n x^{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is this a power series? My book defines power series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n (x-x_0)^n$

Comment: Do you know the root test with a limsup formulation?

Comment: No.Can you explain me,please?

Comment: If $\limsup\limits_{k\to\infty} |a_k|^{1/k}<1$ then the series $\sum a_k$ converges. Write your series in that form. What are the values of $a_k$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: That clearly makes no sense. You have to tell me the formula for all positive integers $k$.

Comment: It would be more useful if you answered my question. You still haven't told me a formula for $a_k$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. *Then* you can apply the formula.

Comment: $a_k=k^k$ for $k\ge1$?

Comment: Hint: the $n$ in your formula $\sum_n n^n x^{n!}$ is not the same as the $n$ in $\sum_n a_n x^n$.  That's why Ted used $k$ rather than $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the series diverges if $|x|>1.$ For $|x|<1,$ apply the ratio test:

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}|x|^{(n+1)!}}{n^{n}|x|^{n!}} = (n+1)(1+1/n)^n|x|^{(n+1)!-n!}.$$

Verify that the expression on the right $\to 0$ to see the power series coverges for such $x.$ It follows that the radius of convergence is $1.$

Comment: The series uniform converges in $[a,b]\subset (-1,1)$?

Comment: Yes, that is true of every power series that converges in $(0,1).$

Answer (score 2):

If $|x| < 1$ then $|n^nx^{n!}| < e^{2n \ln n - n! \ln (\frac{1}{x})} < 2^{-n}$.

So the radius of convergence is 1. (but the series does not converge for $x = \pm 1$.

Comment: This seems obscure to me, could you provide some detail ?

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$ a_m=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
n^n,\text{ if }m=n! \text{ for }n=1,2,3,\cdots,\\
0,\text{ else.}
\end{array}\right. $$
Then 
$$ \limsup_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[m]{a_m}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n!]{n^n}=1 $$
and hence
$$ R=1. $$